# How to properly declare computed property names in TypeScript classes?

Tags: typescript, computed-properties, type-declaration

### In short

How can I declare in TypeScript: *In this class, any property beginning with '$' is a reference to an Element*?

### Context

I have a Custom Element class method that automatically stores any child element having attribute `data-reference` in a property named after its value prefixed by '$'.
It works perfectly in vanilla JavaScript :

```js
class SomeComponent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.setReferences()
    console.log(this.$myRef) // <div data-reference="myRef"></div>
  }

  setReferences() {
    const referencedElements = this.querySelectorAll('[data-reference]')

    referencedElements.forEach((element) => {
      const referenceName = '$' + element.getAttribute('data-reference')
      this[referenceName] = element
    })
  }
}
customElements.define('some-component', SomeComponent)
```

```html
<some-component>
  <div data-reference="myRef"></div>
</some-component>
```

But this won't compile in TypeScript, who doesn't know about `$myRef` property:

```
console.log(this.$myRef) // Property '$myRef' does not exist on type 'SomeComponent'
                 ^^^^^^
```

So far I've come up with 3 workarounds but none of them is fully satisfying.

#### 1. Type assertion

Nope!

```
console.log((this as any).$myRef) // <div data-reference="myRef"></div>
```

The point is to provide a quick access to any `$ref`, so adding `as any` or `<any>` (plus parenthesis) is not a viable solution.

#### 2. Object litteral

Probably the cleanest, but not exactly what I want to achieve.

```
type ElementReferenceMap = { [key: string]: Element }

class SomeComponent extends HTMLElement {
    ref: ElementReferenceMap = {};

    setReferences() {
        const referencedElements = this.querySelectorAll('[data-reference]');

        referencedElements.forEach((element) => {
            const referenceName = element.getAttribute('data-reference');
            this.ref[referenceName] = element as Element;
        })

        console.log(this.ref.myRef); // <div data-reference="myRef"></div>
    }
}
```

By renaming it to `this.$.myRef` I get closer, but it's still not equivalent to the vanilla JavaScript version.

#### 3. Index property

Works as expected (like the JavaScript version), but it doesn't feel right, as it allows any property value.

```
class SomeComponent extends HTMLElement {
    // [x: string]: Element; // conflict with other properties
    [x: string]: any; // ok

    setReferences() {
        const referencedElements = this.querySelectorAll('[data-reference]');

        referencedElements.forEach((element) => {
            const referenceName = '$' + element.getAttribute('data-reference');
            this[referenceName] = element;
        })

        console.log(this.$myRef); // <div data-reference="myRef"></div>
    }
}
```

I may be missing the obvious solution since I'm quite new to TypeScript.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Second option is the way to go. The problem with "any property beginning with '$'" - it can't be really validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way typescript can generate static checks on your html code, it just can't given html being dynamic (you can dynamically generate DOM with `data-reference` attributes) 2 or 3 both are viable options. Just think about this: typescript checks types during compile time, before delivery, when HTML can be populated with extra elements later, during runtime.

If you know your elements beforehand, you could provide static type info for typescript. For example for a (3) option:

```
class SomeComponent extends HTMLElement {
    [x: '$myRef' | '$myOtherRef']: HTMLElement; // ok
    ....
```

Or you could just have a plain property:

```
class SomeComponent extends HTMLElement {
    $myProp: HTMLElement
    ....
```

Comment: Well I wasn't expecting typescript to check directly on HTML, I was rather wondering if there could be a solution similar to your first example, like `[x: '$' + string]: HTMLElement` (of course this makes no sense but you get the idea). Also, the idea was that any `class SomeDerivingComponent extends SomeComponent {}` gets its own refs automatically so I kind of miss the point if I have to explicit them. But I get that what I'm looking for does not exist. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I do not know how good this advice is (meaning please take it with a grain of salt), but what I often end up doing in cases like this - is to generate typescript definitions manually. Like write a small python script that maybe parses your html (or something else, idk?) and generates `.ts` file with type definitions for what you need. This is actually much easier than it sounds, but this is added support.